# How to use data from DB as initial state with Zustand

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, prisma, zustand

I'm using the T3 stack (TypeScript, tRPC, Prisma, Next, etc) and I want to either load data from my database using a tRPC query, or use an empty array in my Zustand store. I keep getting an error saying:

> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem. error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of
>    null (reading 'useContext')
>    (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   page: '/' }

here's the code generating the error:

```
type Image = {
  url: string;
  prompt: string;
};

interface UserState {
  images: Image[] | [];
  isLoading: boolean;
  addImage: (url: string, prompt: string) => void;
  removeImage: (url: string, prompt: string) => void;
  setLoading: () => void;
}

export const useStore = create<UserState>((set) => {
  const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

  const dbImages = trpc.images.list.useQuery({
    limit: 20,
    userId: sessionData?.user?.id ?? "",
  }).data?.items;

  return {
    // initial state
    images: dbImages ? dbImages : [],
    isLoading: false,
    // methods for manipulating state
    addImage: (url, prompt) => {
      set((state) => ({
        images: [
          ...state.images,
          {
            url: url,
            prompt: prompt,
          } as Image,
        ],
      }));
    },
    removeImage: (url: string) => {
      set((state) => ({
        images: state.images?.filter((x) => x.url !== url),
      }));
    },
    setLoading: () => {
      set((state) => ({
        isLoading: !state.isLoading,
      }));
    },
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm still in the learning phases and would appreciate best practices, etc.

Comment: `useQuery` is a React hook which means it can only be used inside a React component. And about loading data from the database (I'm facing the same issue), you can probably try to query the data from Prisma directly in the Zustand file, but then again getting access to the NextAuth session object will be tricky.

Comment: Btw, you cannot use `useSession` either in this file, for the same reason as mentioned in my previous comment